# What determines which English punctuation choices are valid in 1 Corinthians 8:6?

Tags: 1-corinthians, punctuation

In English punctuation is critical for clarity and understanding:  A Panda eats, shoots, and leaves.  A Panda eats shoots and leaves.

> For though there be that are called gods, whether in heaven or in earth, (as there be gods many, and lords many,) But to us there is but one God, the Father, of whom are all things, and we in him; and one Lord Jesus Christ, by whom are all things, and we by him. - 1 Corinthians 8:5-6 KJV

My understanding is that punctuation is not present in the Greek texts and is added according to the grammar of whichever language it is being translated.  My assumption is that there are some clues, in the manuscript texts, as to what punctuation should be used where.

Some English translations (KJV, for example) have a semi-colon after "and we in him".

Other English translations (ESV, for example) do not employ a semi-colon.

I have been unable to find any translations which employ a semi-colon or colon as follows:

For though there be that are called gods, whether in heaven or in earth, (as there be gods many, and lords many,) **But to us there is but one:** God, the Father, of whom are all things, and we in him and one Lord Jesus Christ, by whom are all things, and we by him.

What hermeneutical principles (if any) demand the punctuation as used and rule out the punctuation I have proposed?

Comment: Your translation makes it two not one. One: god the father, and second: Lord Jesus.

Answer (score 4):

OP:

> But to us there is but **one:** God, the Father,

The English word *one* is a noun. Let's see the Greek:

one
εἷς (heis)
**Adjective** - **Nominative Masculine Singular**
Strong's 1520: One. (including the neuter Hen); a primary numeral; one.

εἷς is an adjective, not a noun. Further, Nominative Masculine Singular matches the next word:

God,
Θεὸς (Theos)
**Noun** - **Nominative Masculine Singular**
Strong's 2316: A deity, especially the supreme Divinity; figuratively, a magistrate; by Hebraism, very.

Θεὸς is a noun.

What hermeneutical principles (if any) demand the punctuation as used and rule out the punctuation I have proposed?

εἷς is an adjective, not a noun. There is one what?

Answer (score 4):

I take it that you are prompted by Jesus words 'I and my Father are one'. But the construction here is different.

There is but one God, the Father (...) and one Lord, Jesus Christ (...).

The emphasis, here, is between Deity (the Father) and Lordship (in humanity) : the contrast of 'gods many' and 'lords many'.

Therefore, what you are attempting to do with punctuation is not appropriate. The oneness applies, first, to God - the Father (Deity as such) and then, second, to Lord - Jesus Christ, (Lordship over the Body and Lordship over all creation, via angelic power and authority).